# iOS Swift 4 / Response from cloudant connection

Tags: swift, parsing, cloudant

Currently I have the problem that I use Cloudant and this [library](https://github.com/cloudant/swift-cloudant) to access a noSql database.

I'll get something back, too.

Here's the order:

```
    let read = GetAllDocsOperation(databaseName: dbName){ (response, httpInfo, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Encountered an error while reading a document. Error:\(error)")
        } else {

          print(response)

        }
    }

    client.add(operation:read)
```

And here are my results:

[image: Picture from output]

Now I don't know what to do with it. I first tried parsing it with SwiftyJSON or acting as a dictionary.

Unfortunately, I failed.

Can someone possibly help me?
I am new in swift so please excuse me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to safely unwrap the response, and then access the JSON. This one here is doing manually everything, without encoder, decoder or third parties

```
if let response = response as? [String: Any] {
    if let rowData = response["row"] as? [[String: Any]] {
        for row in rowData {
            if let id = row["id"] as? Int {
                print(id.description)
            } 
            if let key = row["key"] as? Int {
                print(key.description)
            }
            if let value = row["value"] as? [String: Any] {
                if let rev = value["rev"] as? String {
                     print(rev)
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

But I would suggest taking a look [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) which helps you a lot with JSONs or you could give it a try learning  [Encoding and Decoding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) by Apple

Comment: Hi, did it with your code :) Thank you. You are right, I will take a look on this topics now :)